# How do I access IMetaDataEmit and other MetaData COM interfaces from C# or F#?

Tags: c#, com, f#, com-interop

I am writing a compiler in F# and I want to be able to access the [unmanaged metadata COM interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404384.aspx) in the .net runtime. Before anybody mentions it, *Reflection.Emit is not suitable for my purposes*, nor do I want to use any other method than the metadata COM interfaces.

I've imported mscoree.tlb but it doesn't seem to include the interfaces I need.

The interfaces I'm interested in include [IMetaDataEmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230877.aspx). Any sample code relating to this would be very useful, though I've not been able to find any so far.

C# samples would be fine as I can easily convert them to F#.

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help me with this rather cryptic query!

**Update:** I have now got this sorted by writing explicit COM references using the interface GUIDs!

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to create your own project and compile these interfaces (using their definitions from cor.h) into a type library, which you could then tlbimp into a managed assembly. I realize it would be pretty tedious to convert the C header code into IDL, but that could possibly be automated (or partially automated) by some text-processing scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply :-) However I have managed to sort this now using manual COM interfaces based on the GUIDs referenced in cor.h which turned out to be the best approach I think anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found the [mdbg sample](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&displaylang=en) which includes source code for wrapping exactly the interfaces you need.